# Regular Expression matching in ssh config

Tags: ssh, bash, configuration, regular-expressions

I have a bunch of servers with the names srv1.domain.com, srv2.domain.com, ..., srv50.domain.com

I want to be able to connect to these servers by `ssh srv1`

I don't want to put 50 configuration entries to my .ssh/config such as

```
HOST srv1
HOSTNAME srv1.domain.com
USER amac
IdentityFile /home/amac/.ssh/id_rsa
```

What I like is a regular expression matching, which would allow me to write something like

```
HOSTNAME (srv[0-9]*).domain.com
HOST \1
USER amac
IdentityFile /home/amac/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Is this possible? Maybe by creating a bash alias which would convert all instances of "srv(.*)" to srv\1.domain.com, where \1 corresponds to the substring in the paranthesis matched by the regular expression?

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you simply add `domain.com` to your search path in your DNS resolver so that any request to resolve a name `foo` will result in the resolver trying `foo.domain.com`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This sounds like a problem best solved by DNS.  Add this to your `/etc/resolv.conf`:
>
> ```
> search domain.com
> ```
>
> If a DNS lookup contains no dots<sup>1</sup> or returns an NXDOMAIN >response then another DNS lookup will be made with that search value >appended.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> If you do `ssh srv1`, the DNS lookup will be made for `srv1.domain.com`.
>
> If you do `ssh srv1.dc1`, the DNS lookup will be for `srv1.dc1` which will return NXDOMAIN.  The automatic followup DNS lookup will be for `srv1.dc1.domain.com`.
>
> You can add multiple search domains to that line separated by whitespace and they will be tried in the order listed until one of them returns an A record<sup>2</sup>.
>
> 1.) This value is configurable and refers to the number of dots the short name must have fewer than.  The default value is 1 and it should be set higher than 1 for sites where the hosts are of the form `srv1.dc1.domain.com`.  This avoids the useless request to the root servers for the `dc1` top level domain.
>
> 2.) Or an AAAA record.

**Updated answer 25th Nov 2020:**

Although the outdated answer above is still a fully valid one, nowadays, I would rather suggest using the `ssh_config` built-in mechanism `CanonicalDomains`

That would mean, instead of changing `/etc/resolv.conf` or DNS records, you can simply add the following lines to the top of your `ssh_config` file:

```
CanonicalizeHostname yes
CanonicalDomains domain.com
```

Please refer to the [official ssh_config documentation](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#CanonicalDomains) for details around these configuration statements.

Answer (score 5):

[This should do the trick on OpenSSH 5.5 and greater.](http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-5.6)

```
Host *.*
  Hostname %h

Host *
  Hostname %h.domain.com
  IdentityFile /path/to/keyfile.pem
```

The first rule matches any normal domain names and just passes the domain name through.  The second rule handles single word hosts and appends domain.com to the end.

One side effect of this is that even for ssh calls to anotherdomain.com, ssh will try to use the IdentityFile for domain.com. I don't think that matters however.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ProxyCommand` to use `regex` on the host name specified on the command line.

```
Host srv*.domain.com
    User amac
    ProxyCommand nc $(sed -e "s/.domain.com//" <<< "%h") %p
    IdentityFile /home/amac/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now `ssh srv23.domain.com` would connect to `srv23`.

Note, you don't need to specify `HostName`.

Comment: This was perfect for proxying with 2 different bastion hosts:
Host *.2
  ProxyCommand ssh -W $(sed -e "s/.2//" <<< "%h"):%p bastion2

Answer (score 1):

openssh supports patterns (see http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config), but not references to matches (AFAIK).

You can specify wildcards pretty much as you had it in the question:

```
Host srv*.domain.com
  User amac
  IdentityFile /home/amac/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you don't want to have to specify the full hostname, you can either do the dns trick mentioned before (and change the Host line to srv*) or create a shell function as follows:

```
ss() {
  if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "specify a server #, eg ss 10"
  else
    echo "ssh'ing to srv$1.domain.com"
    ssh srv$1.domain.com
  fi
}
```

and use it like:

```
ss 10
```

Easier than changing dns and doesn't cause problems when you want to hit srv01.someotherdomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem that when specifying

```
Host srv*
  Hostname %h.domain.com
```

I could no longer connect using full host names:

```
$ ssh srv677.domain.com
ssh: Could not resolve hostname srv677.domain.com.domain.com: Name or service not known
```

Note that doubling domain.com.

To be able to connect via both short and full forms of host names, I did the following trick:

```
Host srv* !srv*.domain.com
    Hostname %h.domain.com
    User amac
    IdentityFile /home/amac/.ssh/id_rsa

Host srv*.domain.com
    User amac
    IdentityFile /home/amac/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Or even better solution (inspired by this answer https://superuser.com/a/469470):

```
Host *.domain.com srv* vrs*
    User amac
    IdentityFile /home/amac/.ssh/id_rsa

Host !*.domain.com srv* vrs*
    Hostname %h.domain.com
```

It is better because it does not require copying all options twice.